# Abelianization of Lie groups

Tags: linear-algebra, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

If *G* is a group, its **abelianization** is the abelian group *A* and the map *G* → *A* such that any map *G* → *B* with *B* abelian factors through *A*.  Abelianization is a functor, and in general a very lossy operation.  The map *G* → *A* is always a surjection/quotient, because we can construct *A* by dividing *G* by the minimal normal subgroup that contains all conjugations *ghg<sup>-1</sup>h<sup>-1</sup>* for *g,h*∈*G*.

If *V* is a finite-dimensional (super)vector space over a field *K*, then the abelianization of GL(*V*) is isomorphic to the multiplicative group *K*<sup>*</sup> of non-zero numbers in *K*.  Indeed, the determinant exhibits the desired isomorphism.

Here are two questions I'm curious about:

1. What can be said about the abelianizations of other (finite-dimensional) Lie groups?
2. If *V* is an infinite-dimensional vector space, what can be said about the abelianization of GL(*V*)?  Most infinite-dimensional vector spaces have some analytic structure, e.g. topological vector spaces, and so it's reasonable to ask that the operators in GL(*V*) should preserve that structure; you are welcome to take your favorite type of infinite-dimensional vector space and your favorite type of GL(*V*), if you want.

Comment: Mike Hartglass has since asked about the abelianization of GL(H) http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2681/abelianization-of-glh for H an infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have anything to say about specific examples, but here are some general remarks.  A way to construct the abelianization of any compact group is to consider its image under the product of all its 1-dimensional unitary representations.  This is because a compact abelian group is characterized by its set of characters by Pontrjagin duality.  More generally, you can construct the double Pontrjagin dual of a locally compact group to get its locally compact abelianization as a subgroup of a space of maps to U(1) with the compact-open topology.

Answer (score 4):

(In some sense, this is just a restatement of what Eric said above....)

For compact groups, quite a lot can be said.  Every compact group H' has a finite cover H which is Lie group isomorphic to $T^{k} \times G$, where $G$ is compact and simply connected.

Then, one can easily show that [H,H] = {$e$}$\times G$ and hence that the abelianization of $H$ (which, as in the finite case is H/[H,H]) is $T^{k}$.

The same holds true of the original group $H'$: the abelianization is $H'/[H',H']$ and is isomorphic to $T^{k}$.