# Fundamental group of a topological group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fundamental-group

It is well known that the fundamental group of a path-connected topological group is abelian. Suppose that $G$ is a connected topological group and let $Ab(G)$ the abelianization of the topological group $G$. Is there a relation between $\pi_{1}G$ and $\pi_{1}(Ab(G))$ ?

Comment: There's a functorial homomorphism. Have you looked at any examples? Do you have any more precise question?

Comment: @YCor sure, how far the functorial homomorphism from being an isomorphism

Comment: Have you looked at any examples?

Comment: @YCor no, do you have a trivial easy example ?

Comment: SU(2) and SO(3) are good ones...

Comment: @YCor I think in the setting of compact connected Lie groups, it can not happen that $\pi_1(Ab(G))$ is larger than $\pi_1G$. Can this fail for compact connected topological groups?

Comment: What I would have liked to read is the observation that in the easiest examples, the resulting homomorphism is surjective, and not always injective. It's therefore natural to ask whether it's always surjective, and also in the restricted but important setting of connected Lie groups. Also, a side remark is that when $G$ is (possibly) not Hausdorff, the Hausdorffication quotient map $G\to G/_{\overline{\{1\}}}$ induces an isomorphism between $\pi_1$. In particular, looking at $G\to G/[G,G]$ or $G\to\overline{[G,G]}$ does not matter (there are connected Lie groups $G$ with $[G,G]$ not closed).

Comment: There are examples of non-connected Lie groups $G$ for which it's not surjective: for instance, the quotient of the product of $\mathbf{R}$ and the integral Heisenberg group by identifying $\mathbf{Z}$ with the center of the latter. I don't know if such phenomena might be produced in connected, non-path-connected topological groups.

Answer (score 6):

This question is arguably too broad, but I interpret that to mean the OP is somewhat new to this area. So, I'll give some basics, in a CW answer, and I encourage others to add to it if they want to. First, for any group $G$, the abelianization $Ab(G)$ is defined to be the group $G/[G,G]$ where $[G,G]$ is the commutator subgroup. There is a natural quotient map $G \to Ab(G)$. The assignment of $G$ to $Ab(G)$ is also a functor from the category of groups to the category of abelian groups, and this functor realizes the latter as a reflective subcategory of the former.

If $G$ is a topological group, then $G/[G,G]$ can be given the quotient topology. See Section 5 of [these notes](https://www.math.uh.edu/~vern/grouprepn.pdf). A common situation of interest is when $G$ is a (compact) Lie group. Taking the fundamental group is a functor $X\mapsto \pi_1(X)$ to the category of groups. Note that $\pi_1(G)$ does *not* need to be a topological group. [See the thesis of Jeremy Brazas](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3972). Because $\pi_1$ is a functor, there is a natural homomorphism $\pi_1(G) \to \pi_1(Ab(G))$. The comments demonstrate that this morphism need not be injective or surjective in general. Here are some links where examples are computed: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509869/what-is-the-abelianization-of-sl2-mathbbz-p), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2677/abelianization-of-lie-groups), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2681/abelianization-of-glh).

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is a compact connected Lie group, then standard classification results show that there is a diagram $G\xleftarrow{f}H\xrightarrow{g}T\times K$, where $f$ and $g$ are surjective with finite kernel (and so are coverings), and $T$ is a torus, and $K$ is a finite product of simple Lie groups, which have finite fundamental groups.  This gives maps $\pi_1(G)\xleftarrow{\pi_1(f)}\pi_1(H)\xrightarrow{\pi_1(g)}\pi_1(T)\times\pi_1(K)$, where $\pi_1(f)$ and $\pi_1(g)$ are injective with finite cokernel.  This shows that $\pi_1(G)$, $\pi_1(H)$ and $\pi_1(T)$ are the same up to a finite error.  We also get 
surjective homomorphisms $\text{Ab}(G)\xleftarrow{\text{Ab}(f)}\text{Ab}(H)\xrightarrow{\text{Ab}(g)}\text{Ab}(T\times K)=T$, where $\text{Ab}(G)$ and $\text{Ab}(H)$ are compact connected abelian Lie groups and therefore tori.  There are a few more details to sort out, but I am pretty sure that $\text{Ab}(f)$ and $\text{Ab}(g)$ are again finite coverings so $\pi_1(\text{Ab}(G))$ and $\pi_1(\text{Ab}(H))$ are again the same as $\pi_1(T)$ up to a finite error.  For any given $G$ it should not be hard to pin down the details and find $\text{Ab}(G)$ and $\pi_1(\text{Ab}(G))$ explicitly.

As a consequence of the Peter-Weyl Theorem, an arbitrary compact Hausdorff group can be written as the inverse limit of a filtered diagram of compact Lie groups, and one could use this to transfer some results from the Lie case to the general case.

For any connected Lie group $G$, there is a maximal compact subgroup $G_0\leq G$ such that the inclusion $G_0\to G$ is a homotopy equivalence.  One should be able to learn something from this, but I have not thought through the details.

Comment: There's no obvious reduction from connected Lie groups to the easy case of compact connected Lie groups, because taking the abelianization does not commute with "passing to a maximal compact subgroup". To be more concrete, if $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ then abelianization induces $\mathbf{Z}\to 0$ on $\pi_1$, but for the maximal compact subgroups, it induces the identity of $\mathbf{Z}$.